# I need to run command that in string

Tags: c#, sql, string, command, radix-sort

I have a problem with code.
I want to implement radix sort to numbers on c# by using ling.

I give as input string and give 0 in the start of the number:

```
            foreach(string number in numbers){<br>
               if(number.lenth > max_lenth) max_lenth = number.lenth;<br><br>

            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.lenth; i++){<br>
               while(numbers[i].length < max_lenth) numbers[i] = "0" + numbers[i];<br><br>
```

after this I need to order by each number in string, but it doesn't work with my loop:

```
        var output = input.OrderBy(x => x[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < max_lenth; i++)
        {
            output = output.ThenBy(x => x[i]);
        }
```

so I think to create a string that contain  "input.OrderBy(x => x[0]);" and add "ThenBy(x => x[i]);"
while max_length - 1 and activate this string that will my result.
How can I implement it?
I can't use ling as a tag because its my first post

Comment: in a third loop was "int i = 1;" I just forget about it, sorry

Comment: Even though you figured out the problem yourself, you may want to edit your question to make it more clear. What is "numbers"? It this Razor or something like that (I ask because of the <br> tags). When you say "it doesn't work", what does it do instead? What do you expect, what result do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question, you are looking for a solution to the problem you are trying to solve using Linq (by the way, the last letter is a Q, not a G - which is likely why you could not add the tag).

The rest of your question isn't quite clear to me.  I've listed possible solutions based on various assumptions:

I am assuming your array is of type string[]. Example:

`string[] values = new [] { "708", "4012" };`

To sort by alpha-numeric order regardless of numeric value order:

`var result = values.OrderBy(value => value);`

To sort by numeric value, you can simply change the delegate used in the OrderBy clause assuming your values are small enough:

`var result = values.OrderBy(value => Convert.ToInt32(value));`

Let us assume though that your numbers are arbitrarily long, and you only want the values in the array as they are (without prepending zeros), and that you want them sorted in integer value order:

```cs
string[] values = new [] { "708", "4012" };
int maxLength = values.Max(value => value.Length);
string zerosPad = string
    .Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat<string>("0", maxLength));

var resultEnumerable = values
   .Select(value => new 
      { 
         ArrayValue = value, 
         SortValue = zerosPad.Substring(0, maxLength - value.Length) + value 
      }
   )
   .OrderBy(item => item.SortValue);

foreach(var result in resultEnumerable)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", result.SortValue, result.ArrayValue);
}
```

The result of the above code would look like this:

0708   708

4012   4012

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try `Array.Sort(x)` or `Array.Sort(x,StringComparer.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: Hey Nik! Code-only answers may solve the problem but they are much more useful if you explain how they solve it. Community requires theory as well as code both to understand your answer fully.